# ExtJS radio group - how to set value based on user confirmation?

Tags: extjs, radio-button, extjs5, radio-group

I have a radio group field with two radio buttons in it. One radio button is checked by default. When I click on the other, change event triggers and renders a confirmation message stating YES or NO. if YES is clicked then the value will change. If NO is clicked value should remain the same.

e.g. Item 2 is selected by default. If I click on Item 1, then click on NO. the Item 2 should be checked but not Item 1.

```
var RG = Ext.create({
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Two Columns',
        // Arrange radio buttons into two columns, distributed vertically
        columns: 2,
        vertical: true,
        items: [
            { boxLabel: 'Item 1', name: 'rb', inputValue: '1' },
            { boxLabel: 'Item 2', name: 'rb', inputValue: '2', checked: true}
        ],
        listeners:{
            'change':function(cmp, newValue, oldValue){
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title:'Save Changes?',
                    message: 'Would you like to save your changes?',
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                    icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
                    fn: function(btn) {
                        if (btn === 'yes') {
                            alert('Yes pressed');
                        } else if (btn === 'no') {
                            alert('No pressed');
                            //New Code
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'RadioGroup Example',
    width: 300,
    height: 125,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items:[RG]
});
```

Please let me know how to make proper changes to achieve this behavior.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

First supend change event then set the component with old value again resume change Event ,Find the code below

```
      Ext.Msg.show({
                title:'Save Changes?',
                message: 'Would you like to save your changes?',
                buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
                fn: function(btn) {
                    if (btn === 'yes') {
                        alert('Yes pressed');
                    } else if (btn === 'no') {
                        cmp.suspendEvent('change');
                        cmp.setValue(oldValue);
                        cmp.resumeEvent('change');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: cmp.reset(); instead of  cmp.setValue(oldValue); also works

Answer (score 1):

The scenario that you are looking for can be achieved with the controller. Give a function name to your change listener as follows:
listeners: {
                        change: 'applicantRadioChange'
                    }

Write this function in controller as:

```
applicantRadioChange : function(cmp,newValue,oldValue){

if(newValue != oldValue)
{
Ext.Msg.show({
                            title:'Save Changes?',
                            message: 'Would you like to save your changes?',
                            buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                            icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
                            fn: function(btn) {
                                if (btn === 'yes') {
                                    alert('Yes pressed');
                                } else if (btn === 'no') {
                                    cmp.setValue(oldValue);

                                }
                            }
                        });

}
```

Comment: this has problem if you set oldvalue without suspending change event it will again fire the change event and may become recursive.

Comment: Its not becoming recursive at my end. Actually Ext.Msg works only if layout is not suspended so that's not needed. Anyways other thing is that, in Ext.Msg.Show in the main view file, you can't find cmp,oldValue and newValue so u need it in controller.

Comment: set.Cmp(oldValue) is a change it will fire for sure. check fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r0t and click no it will fire again.

Comment: It doesn't matter listener is at view or controller we will get all the arguments in the callback